# How to combine multiple Excel files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel files in the same format and I want to combine them into a single file.

How can I merge them into one single excel file using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

VBA is no longer required to merge files. You can use Power Query and merge all files in the same folder with just a few clicks. When the files change, you just update the query.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn but I dont have power query in my computer.

Comment: It's a [free download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=39379) for Excel 2010 and 2013 and it is built into Excel 2016 as Get & Transform. .

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. a "flat" file, in which all the data are in a single sheet (BAD)
2. A multi-sheet file (GOOD)

In the first case open a new file, cut and paste your existing content into the new (single) sheet

In the second case Move/Copy the sheets to a New Document.

There: you now have enough Google fodder to get you started.

Comment: your answer does not help . do you know vba for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue a while back and found an excellent solution thanks to my good friend Google.  All credit for this solution goes to the following page: [computer hope](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001376.htm)

To merge Microsoft Excel files together, save them as CSV files first (it would be possible to automate this part in VBA if there is a recurrent need). Open the Excel files and in the menu bar, click File, then Save As. In the Save as type drop-down list, select CSV (comma delimited) (*.csv) from the list.

Do this for each Excel file you want to merge, then place all the CSV files in the same folder. For ease, place them in a folder in the root of the C: drive (e.g., c:\csvfiles).

Open the **Windows command prompt** (to get to this, in the Search or Run line, type cmd and press return) and navigate to the folder containing the CSV files. Type dir to view the files in the folder and ensure all the files are there.

Type in the following command to merge all CSV files in the folder into a new CSV file titled "newfile.csv" (any name could be used):

```
copy *.csv newfile.csv
```

After the new file is created, open the new CSV file in Microsoft Excel and save it as an Excel file.